# using request-promise to get a github url returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, request-promise

I'm trying to use `request-promise` to get a github url, it works on browser but I'm getting 404 returned via node.js, not sure if I'm not setting headers correctly:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const result = await rp.get('https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/21140');
// result.statusCode is 404 here
```

This is just one example, the goal is to build a checker service that checks if links are broken regardless of domain.

Comment: That URL works fine in `curl` without any special headers. Is this running in a browser or Node?

Comment: When I test your code locally, `result` is a string (the response body) but it seems to work just fine

Comment: In fact, if the response was a 404, I wouldn't expect the promise to resolve. This should be throwing an error / promise rejection. Are you absolutely sure this is your exact code and that `result.statusCode` is defined (FYI, it shouldn't be) and the value is `404`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong to me...I tried running your code, instead of request-promise, i promisified request.get method. Refer to screenshot below : [image]